# How to check if consecutive digits in a number are even or odd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, nested-lists

I am doing some exercises and learning Python. I need to be able to check for an input number whether its consecutive digits are even or odd. So, if the first number is odd, the next should be even and so on in order for the terms to comply. I have the following code:

```
def par_nepar(n):
    cifre = []

    while n != 0:
        cifre.append(n % 10)
        n //= 10

    cifre = cifre[::-1]
    ind = cifre[0]
    for broj in cifre:
        if cifre[0] % 2 == 0:
            # for br in range(len(cifre)):
            if cifre[ind + 1] % 2 != 0:
                ind = cifre[ind+1]

n = int(input("Unesite broj n: "))
print(par_nepar(n))
```

As you can see, I am struggling with index looping. I took the input number and transformed it into a list. Created a variable for index[0] and don't really know how to loop through consecutive indexes. I know I might be able to use zip or enumerate but I think that is not a truly pythonic solution here and probably there is a simpler way to loop over consecutive list numbers and compare them to index[-1].

Input examples:

```
>>>print(par_nepar(2749)) # Every consecutive digits shifts odd->even or even->odd
True
>>>print(par_nepar(2744)) # Two last digits are even
False
```

Comment: Can you give a simple example for input and desired output? This might help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
def par_nepar(n):

    split = [int(i) for i in str(n)]. 

    for i in range(1,len(split)):

        if (split[i] % 2 == 0) ^ (split[i-1] % 2 == 1):
            return False

    return True
```

Works as:

1. Converts integer to list: 1234 -> [1,2,3,4]
2. iterate the elements (excluding the first)
3. XOR condition that takes `False` if two consecutive digits are even or odd.

Tests:

```
>>> print(par_nepar(2749))
True

>>> print(par_nepar(2744))
False
```

Answer (score 1):

mine solution is very simple. just change a bit your code and avoiding using indexes just looping through all digits in cifre and handling boolean flags:

```
def par_nepar(n):
    cifre = []

    while n != 0:
        cifre.append(n % 10)
        n //= 10

    even = True
    odd = True
    output = "The number complies to the needed terms"

    for broj in cifre:
        if broj % 2 == 0 and odd:
            even = True
            odd = False
        elif broj % 2 != 0 and even:
            odd = True
            even = False
        else:
            return "The number doesn't comply to the needed terms."
    return output
n = int(input("Unesite broj n: "))
print(par_nepar(n))
```

outputs:

```
Unesite broj n: 33890
The number doesn't comply to the needed terms.

Unesite broj n: 4963850
The number complies to the needed terms
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of getting an integer as input you can get a string and convert it to a list of integers

```
def par_nepar(n):
    s,h=0,0
    for i in range(len(n)-1):
        if n[i]%2==0 and n[i+1]%2!=0:
            s+=1
        elif n[i]%2!=0 and n[i+1]%2==0:
            h+=1
    if s==len(n)//2 or h==len(n)//2:
        print("The number complies to the needed terms")
    else:
        print("The number does not complies to the needed terms")

# list of digits in the provided input
n = list(map(lambda x: int(x),list(input("Unesite broj n: "))))
par_nepar(n)
```

Comment: What is the logic/reasoning behind accepting string as input and then converting it to a list of numbers?

Comment: because the program wants to iterate throught the digits of the given number

Comment: my Q remains the same. I think there has to be a way other then data type conversion.

Comment: @mnm In the question he is getting an integer input and passing it into the function where he then converts the integer to a list of digits using while loop. Instead of doing this in a long way i got the input with a string than converted to list of integers which does the above process in single line

Comment: its sad for you but my Q still remains the same. Besides, no need to explain me what the OP wants or what you've proposed. I'll reiterate, my point is **can the data type conversion be avoided?** Furthermore, one line solution or multiple line solution is not the concern here.

Comment: @mnm nope the data type conversion is needed in my code , if you don't want any data type conversion than you should get a integer input and the iterate it through while and append it to a new list

Comment: precisely, and this is what the OP Q was about. What you have proposed is an alternative approach to solve the OP Q . And thus the Q remains the same, **can datatype conversion be avoided** to obtain a solution to the OP Q?

Comment: But he never wanted to avoid datatype conversion he just got stuck in  looping through the consecutive digits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214879/discussion-between-mnm-and-tonystark).

Answer (score 0):

```
def par_nepar(n):
    cifre = list(str(n))
    flg = False
    if int(cifre[0]) % 2 == 0:
        flg = True
    for d in cifre[1:]:
        _flg = False
        if int(d) % 2 == 0:
            _flg = True
        if not flg^_flg:
            print("The number does not complies to the needed terms")
            return
        flg = _flg
    print("The number complies to the needed terms")
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would also like this one liner.

In a single loop, we find if the number mod 2 is the same as the (first number + the index) mod 2.

This works for you alternating use case.

```
par_nepar = lambda x: all([(int(k) % 2) == ((i + int(str(x)[0])) % 2) for (i, k) in enumerate(str(x))])

print(par_nepar(2749))
print(par_nepar(2744))

# Output
True
False
```

Or if you want with the strings you said, slightly bigger

```
par_nepar = lambda x: 'The number complies to the needed terms. ' if all(
    [(int(k) % 2) == ((i + int(str(x)[0])) % 2) for (i, k) in
     enumerate(str(x))]) else "The number doesn't comply to the needed terms."

#Output
The number complies to the needed terms.
The number doesn't comply to the needed terms.
```